JsonPath using Jayway - check value not exists in array
Given the following JSON:
{
    "id": "0001",
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" }
        ]
}

I would like to return true or equivalent if id 5001 does not exist in the array. Should also return true if the array is empty.
$.topping[?((!(@.id == '5001') && ($.topping empty false)) || ($.topping empty true))]

Returns with the data excluded. How can I tell if the filter applied?
Tested on https://www.javainuse.com/jsonpath
